# SQL Server update and insert based on joining 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, insert-update, join

I have 2 tables which are exactly identical: table1 (a, b, c) and table2 (a, b, c)

But every night, `t2` gets updated and after that update, I want to join these two tables and if the the row exists in `t1`, then update `t1.b`, but if not then insert the row from `t2` into `t1`.

I know this works because it is select

```
SELECT 
    (CASE
        WHEN t1.a IS NOT NULL 
            THEN t1.b + t2.b
        ELSE t2.b
    END) AS 'total new amount'
FROM
    table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN 
    table2 t2 ON t2.a = t1.a AND t2.c = t1.c
```

But how can I do the update and insert?

UPDATE:

so I figured I have to use MERGE command

```
MERGE table1 as t1 
USING table2 as t2 
ON (t1.a = t2.a AND t1.c = t2.c ) 
when MATCHED T
HEN UPDATE SET t1.b = t1.b + t2.b 
when NOT MATCHED 
THEN insert (a,b,c) VALUES (t2.a,t2.b,t2.c);
```

but now i am getting this error:

The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you had a look into [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Hi @Larnu , yea I am trying to understand how merge works

Comment: What have you tried so far then, can you show us? What errors did you get, or what didn't work as you expected?

Comment: MERGE table1 as t1
USING table2 as t2
ON (t1.a = t2.a AND t1.c = t2.c )
when MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET t1.b = t1.b + t2.b
when NOT MATCHED THEN
 insert (a,b,c) 
 VALUES (t2.a,t2.b,t2.c);   

but I am getting this Error:
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @marc_s this is one of the main issues in this interface. we cannot have a discussion here. Sometimes we need to use code in order to explain something which is not yet the answer. We cannot post it in comment (as you said) but it is not answer which mean we cannot post it as answer as well (I am not talking about this case which you can consider the comment as answer but cases that we want to comment).

Comment: I agree - it often takes a lot of "comment" effort to extract the real issue from a question missing detail (like this one). As an example I am now going to post an answer which is probably incorrect due to lack of detail

Comment: You could of course convert your current problem entirely using change tracking.....

Answer (score 0):

> > But every night, t2 gets updated and after that update, I want to join these two tables and if the the row exists in t1, then update t1.b, but if not then insert the row from t2 into t1.

Does anything happen to t1?

If nothing changes in `t1`, the *simplest* way to sync the tables is to just truncate and reload

Depending on how many records in the table and the rate of change, this might be faster or slower than doing an upsert.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE T1;

INSERT INTO T1 (Col1,Col2,Col3)
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM T2;
```

Depending on how frequently T1 is used, there are ways to make this transparent to the end user. (i.e. they'll never see an empty table)

Some methods are:

- Use snapshot isolation and a transaction
- Use a staging table and `SWITCH PARTITION` https://littlekendra.com/2017/01/19/why-you-should-switch-in-staging-tables-instead-of-renaming/
- Use a staging table and `sp_rename`

`MERGE` is certainly one way to do an upsert but seperate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements are often easier to debug and perform better.